# How to play a sound with shake gesture for each collectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created a collectionView and it is horizontally scrollable. What i want is, when for example i am on the first cell and shake my device i want to play the first sound in an array. And when i am on the second file and shake my device i want to play the second file inside my array.

I have got this far:

```
var selectedIndex : Int = 0

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?)
    {

       // var currentRow = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: self.collectionView.visibleCells[0])?.row

        if selectedIndex == 0 {
            do
            {
                audioPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:Sound1!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer1.numberOfLoops = 0
            audioPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer1.play()
        } else if selectedIndex == 1 {
            do
            {
                audioPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:Sound2!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer2.numberOfLoops = 0
            audioPlayer2.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer2.play()

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a var selectedIndex : Int

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
 {
   selectedIndex = indexPath.row
}
```

Now u can access your array with selectedIndex and play sound of selected cell

Comment: ok i did it. But it did not work. I don't know what i did wrong. I have edited my code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it worked!!

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?)
    {

       let currentRow = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: self.collectionView.visibleCells[0])?.row

        if currentRow == 0 {

            do
            {
                audioPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:Sound1!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer1.numberOfLoops = 0
            audioPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer1.play()

        } else if currentRow == 1 {

            do
            {
                audioPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:Sound2!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer2.numberOfLoops = 0
            audioPlayer2.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer2.play()

        }


        }
```